# Login remember me cookies are not setting

Tags: php, cookies, mysqli

I just added a checkbox for my login form. If the user ticks the box, it should store the email and hashed password. Currently, it's not storing the cookie. Also the first time I ever worked with setting a cookie.

This is my checkbox part of the form:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="remember-user cb" name="remember" value="yes" <?php if(isset($_COOKIE['cookemail']) && ($_COOKIE['cookpass'])) {echo 'checked="checked"';}else {echo '';}?>>Remember me
```

This is the part of my 'do-login.php' (which will be called upon submitting the login form):

```
$email = veilig($mysqli,$_POST['email']); 
$password = safe($mysqli,$_POST['password']);
$remember = safe($mysqli,$_POST['remember']);

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT user_id, password, salt FROM members WHERE email = ? LIMIT 1");
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $email); 
    $stmt->execute();  
    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->bind_result($user_id, $db_password, $salt);
    $stmt->fetch();

    //Hashed password
    $saltedPW =  $password . $salt;
    $hashedPW = hash('sha256', $saltedPW);

    //Check if the user exists
    if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {

        //Check of the password is correct
        if ($db_password == $hashedPW) {

            //Cookie the input fields
            $year = time() + 2592000; // 30 DAGEN
            if($remember == "yes") {
                setcookie('cookemail', $email, $year);
                setcookie('cookpass', $password, $year);
            }

            $user_id = preg_replace("/[^0-9]+/", "", $user_id);
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;

            $email = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+/","", $email);
            $_SESSION['email'] = $email;

            echo "succesLogin";

        } else {

            echo "wrongPassword";

        }
```

Am I missing something?

Edit: cookies are now being set! Changed code into:

```
if ($db_password == $hashedPW) {

                //Set cookie when user has succesfully logged in
                $year = time() + 2592000; // 30 DAGEN

                //Random text
                $secret_emword = "dinosaurs are way too cool for our universe";
                $secret_pword = "i eat lots of jelly beans and i regret nothing";

                if($remember == "yes") {
                    setcookie('Auth_', hash('sha256', $email . $secret_emword), $year);
                    setcookie('A_chkx2_', hash('sha256', $password . $secret_pword), $year);

                    //Make sessions
                    $_COOKIE['Auth_'] = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+/","", $_COOKIE['Auth_']);
                    $_SESSION['Auth_'] = $_COOKIE['Auth_'];
                    $_SESSION['A_chkx2_'] = $_COOKIE['A_chkx2_'];
                }

            $user_id = preg_replace("/[^0-9]+/", "", $user_id);
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;

            $email = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+/","", $email);
            $_SESSION['email'] = $email;

            echo "succesLogin";

        } else {

            echo "wrongPassword";

        }
```

Only problem I'm currently facing is the fact that I will not keep signed in until the cookie expires or I sign off. Below is my login_check function:

```
//Check if user has been logged in
function login_check($mysqli) {
    if (isset($_COOKIE['Auth_'], $_COOKIE['A_chkx2_'])) {

        return true;

    } else if (isset($_SESSION['email'], $_SESSION['user_id'])) {

        $email = $_SESSION['email'];
        $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];

        return true;

    } else {
    // Not signed in
        return false;

    }   

}
```

Any idea?

Comment: `session_start();` at the top?

Comment: @jeroen Jups, both files :)

Comment: Any output (php warnings, etc.) before you set the cookie? Also, the cookie will be available on the next page load, not in the page where you set it. By the way, `setcookie()` returns `true` or `false` (on failure), have you checked the return value?

Comment: try putting some king of output (or output variable) inside the `if($remember == "yes") {` section to see if you are ever getting inside that section at all. your `$remember` variable might not be getting set right(the way you expect) in the first place. It is possible that the cookies are not being set because you never get into that `if` statement.

Comment: @jeroen No warnings. Basically I've got a login-form on the profile page. On the profile page I check whether the user has logged in or not. If the user is not logged in, it shows the login-form. After filling in the form and submitting it (via ajax) it reloads the page so the locked content appears.

Comment: @JosephNeathawk I'm getting the debug-alert saying the cookie has been set. It's still not setting though :')

Comment: have you looked inside your browsers privacy setting to see if the cookie is actually there?

Comment: @JosephNeathawk Yes I have, and its not. I've been checking it there the whole time.

Comment: @JosephNeathawk In firefox it seems to be storing now. Only problem is; it's not hashed at all. I guess it's not smart to store the password cookie, is it?

Comment: storing an unencrypted password is not safe no matter where you store it IMO.

Comment: @JosephNeathawk Last question: Is it safe to use the hashed password as password cookie? ( $hashedPW )?

Comment: that should be fine. once its encrypted it can be stored pretty much anywhere reliably.

Comment: I've done it slightly different, see my edited post above. The only problem I'm currently facing is that it will not keep me signed on until I log off or the cookie expires.. :/